# Angular 4 Form value is not cleared on even new form group

Tags: angular, angular4-forms

I've a form class in Angular application having the following code:

```
import { 
  OnInit, 
  OnDestroy, 
  Injector 
}                                   from "@angular/core";
import { 
  FormBuilder, 
  FormGroup, 
  Validators 
}                                   from "@angular/forms";
import { 
  Observable, 
  Subscription 
}                                   from "rxjs";
import { inject }                   from "@angular/core/testing";

import { ActivatedRoute }           from '@angular/router';
import { TranslateService }         from 'ng2-translate';


import { AccessRoleSandbox }        from '../../role.sandbox';
import { AccessPermissionSandbox }  from '../../../permission/permission.sandbox';
import RoleForm                     from '../../models/role-form.model';
import Role                         from "../../models/role.model";
import Permission                   from "../../../permission/models/permission.model";

/**
 * Role form container class
 * 
 * @export
 * @class RoleFormContainer
 */
export class RoleFormContainer implements OnInit, OnDestroy{

  /**
   * Translate service
   * 
   * @protected
   * @type {TranslateService}
   * @memberof RoleFormContainer
   */
  protected translateService: TranslateService;

  /**
   * Form Builder
   * 
   * @protected
   * @type {FormBuilder}
   * @memberof RoleFormContainer
   */
  protected formBuilder: FormBuilder;

  /**
   * Activated route
   * 
   * @protected
   * @type {ActivatedRoute}
   * @memberof RoleFormContainer
   */
  protected route: ActivatedRoute;

  /**
   * Role create/update form
   * 
   * @type {FormGroup}
   * @memberof UpdateRoleContainer
   */
  public form: FormGroup;

  /**
   * Access role sandbox
   * 
   * @protected
   * @type {AccessRoleSandbox}
   * @memberof RoleFormContainer
   */
  protected accessRoleSandbox: AccessRoleSandbox;

  /**
   * Access permission sandbox
   * 
   * @protected
   * @type {AccessPermissionSandbox}
   * @memberof RoleFormContainer
   */
  protected accessPermissionSandbox: AccessPermissionSandbox;

  /**
   * Role ID
   * 
   * @private
   * @type {number}
   * @memberof UpdateRoleContainer
   */
  protected roleId: number;

  /**
   * All permissions object
   * 
   * @type {Array<any>}
   * @memberof CreateRoleContainer
   */
  public allPermissions: Array<any>;

  /**
   * Selected permissions
   * 
   * @type {Array<any>}
   * @memberof RoleFormContainer
   */
  public selectedPermissions: Array<any> = [];

  /**
   * Multiselect dropdown settings
   * 
   * @type {*}
   * @memberof CreateRoleContainer
   */
  public multiselectSettings: any;

  /**
   * Subscriptions
   * 
   * @type {Array<Subscription>}
   * @memberof RoleFormContainer
   */
  public subscriptions: Array<Subscription>;

  /**
   * Form title
   * 
   * @type {string}
   * @memberof RoleFormContainer
   */
  public formTitle: string;

  /**
   * Loading icon on submit button decider
   * 
   * @type {Observable<any>}
   * @memberof RoleFormContainer
   */
  public loadingObservable$: Observable<any>;

  /**
   * Creates an instance of RoleFormContainer.
   * 
   * @param {Injector} injector 
   * @memberof RoleFormContainer
   */
  constructor(
    injector: Injector
  ) {
      this.accessRoleSandbox        = injector.get(AccessRoleSandbox);
      this.accessPermissionSandbox  = injector.get(AccessPermissionSandbox);
      this.translateService         = injector.get(TranslateService);
      this.formBuilder              = injector.get(FormBuilder);
      this.route                    = injector.get(ActivatedRoute);

      this.createForm();
  }

  /**
   * On Init container
   * 
   * @memberof CreateRoleContainer
   */
  ngOnInit() {

  }

  /**
   * Unsubscribe from all Observables
   * 
   * @memberof CreateRoleContainer
   */
  public ngOnDestroy() {

  }

  /**
   * Register subscriptions
   * 
   * @memberof CreateRoleContainer
   */
  public registerSubscriptions() {
    const allPermissions$ = this.accessPermissionSandbox.permissions$;
    const viewingRole$    = this.accessRoleSandbox.viewingRole$;

    const routerSubscription = this.route.params.subscribe(params => {
      if(params && params.hasOwnProperty('id')) {
        this.roleId = params['id'];
        this.accessRoleSandbox.viewRole(this.roleId);
      }
    });

    const viewRoleSubscription = viewingRole$.switchMap(
      () => allPermissions$,
      (role: Role, perms: Array<Permission>) => {
        this.allPermissions = this.normalizePermissions(perms);
        return role;
      }
    ).subscribe(role => this.updateFormValues(role));

    this.subscriptions = [routerSubscription, viewRoleSubscription];
  }

  /**
   * Un-register subscriptions
   * 
   * @memberof RoleFormContainer
   */
  public unregisterSubscriptions() {
    this.subscriptions.forEach(sub => sub.unsubscribe());
  }

  /**
   * Create form
   * 
   * @memberof RoleFormContainer
   */
  private createForm() {
    this.form = this.getForm();
  }

  /**
   * Get form
   * 
   * @private
   * @returns {FormGroup} 
   * @memberof RoleFormContainer
   */
  private getForm(): FormGroup {
    return this.formBuilder.group({
      name:         ["", Validators.required],
      sort:         ["", Validators.required],
      status:       ["", Validators.required]
    });
  }

  /**
   * Update form values
   * 
   * @param {Role} role 
   * @memberof RoleFormContainer
   */
  private updateFormValues(role: Role) {
    if(role) {
      this.form.setValue({
        name:           role.name,
        sort:           role.sort,
        status:         role.status
      });
    }
  }
}
```

**Here is the html file**

```
<div class="card">
  <form [formGroup]="form" novalidate (ngSubmit)="onSubmit($event, form.value)">
    <div class="card-header">
      <i class="fa fa-tag"></i> {{ formTitle }}
    </div>
    <div class="card-body">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-8">
          <div class="form-group row">
            <label class="col-md-3 col-form-label" for="text-input">{{'accessRole.lbl.roleName' | translate}}*</label>
            <div class="col-md-9">
                <div class="input-group">
                  <input 
                  type="text" 
                  id="name" 
                  name="name" 
                  class="form-control" 
                  placeholder="{{'lbl.enter' | translate}} {{'accessRole.lbl.roleName' | translate}}..." 
                  formControlName="name"
                  >
                  <div class="input-group-append">
                    <span class="input-group-text"><i class="fa fa-tag"></i></span>
                  </div>
                </div>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="form-group row">
            <label class="col-md-3 col-form-label" for="text-input">{{'accessRole.lbl.sort' | translate}}*</label>
            <div class="col-md-9">
                <div class="input-group">
                  <input 
                  type="number" 
                  id="sort" 
                  name="sort" 
                  class="form-control" 
                  placeholder="{{'lbl.enter' | translate}} {{'accessRole.lbl.sort' | translate}}..." 
                  formControlName="sort"
                  >
                  <div class="input-group-append">
                    <span class="input-group-text"><i class="fa fa-sort-numeric-desc"></i></span>
                  </div>
                </div>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="form-group row">
            <label class="col-md-3 col-form-label" for="text-input">{{'accessRole.lbl.active' | translate}}</label>
            <div class="col-md-9 centered-checkbox">
              <label class="switch switch-text switch-primary-outline-alt">
                <input type="checkbox" class="switch-input" formControlName="status">
                <span class="switch-label" data-on="Yes" data-off="No"></span>
                <span class="switch-handle"></span>
              </label>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="form-group row">
            <label class="col-md-3 col-form-label" for="text-input">{{'accessRole.lbl.associatedPermissions' | translate}}</label>
            <div class="col-md-9 centered-checkbox">
                <angular2-multiselect [data]="allPermissions" [(ngModel)]="selectedPermissions" 
                  [settings]="multiselectSettings"
                  formControlName="permissions">
                </angular2-multiselect>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="card-footer">
      <button class="btn btn-outline-primary px-3" [disabled]="form.invalid" type="submit">
        {{'btn.lbl.submit' | translate}}
      </button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-outline-danger" routerLink="/admin/access/role/list"><i class="fa fa-arrow-left"></i> {{'btn.lbl.goBack' | translate}}</button>
    </div>
  </form>
</div>
```

This class is extended by both `create-role.container.ts` and `update-role.container.ts` components. They both are having separate html files in which the form is rendered.

The problem is, I'm going to update form to update and role and come back on listing. Then I go to the create page, the form values are not cleared while, you can see I'm building the form from scrach in the constructor.

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer as it was due to the observable I've set for viewRole$. So when each time we come to the form, this subscription gets enabled and it updates the last state of the viewingRole$.